# RequireJS loading file from wrong host

Tags: javascript, heroku, amazon-s3, requirejs

I have an issue with RequireJS where it is loading just one file from the wrong host. I am running my application on Heroku, but I have my static files loaded onto S3. When I load the home page, the RequireJS main file is loaded correctly from S3, but the`deps` declared in the main file is not loaded from S3 but from Heroku.

Here is the the HTML script tag that loads RequireJS and the main file correctly.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/webpages/js/libs/require.js" data-main="https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/webpages/js/main.js"></script>
</head>
```

Now here is the `main.js` file:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/static/webpages/js",
    paths: {
        angular : "libs/angular/angular",
        angularAMD : "libs/angular/angular-amd.min",
        angularUiRouter : "libs/angular/angular-ui-router.min",
        angularLocalStorage: "libs/angular/angular-local-storage.min",
        bootstrap: "libs/bootstrap.min",
        jquery: "libs/jquery.min",
        app : "app"
    },
    shim : {
        'angular' : {'exports' : 'angular'},
        'angularUiRouter' : ['angular'],
        'angularLocalStorage' : ['angular'],
        'bootstrap' : ['jquery']
    },
    deps: ['app']
});
```

For some reason, RequireJS attempts to load the dependency `app` from Heroku rather than S3. `app.js` is located right under the `baseUrl`. I would love to know if there is some configuration issues here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Getting around this issue required a bit of a hack.

1) I grabbed the value of `data-main` from the `<script>` elem that links RequireJS

2) In the `main.js` file, I parse this value and grab the host url value. Something like `http://hostname.com/`

3) I then prepend this value to the `baseUrl` config setting like this:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: hostURl + "static/webpages/js"
});
```

Now require loads all the files from my S3 bucket.